# puppeteer .match, how to get the console to log all of contents of string instead of just my search

Tags: javascript, discord, puppeteer

First time asking a question here but I am proper stuck. Im working on discord and we have a ticket system where I grab the users information and then input it to another site.

discord debug:

```
<li id="chat-messages-1041534337184710696" class="messageListItem-ZZ7v6g" aria-setsize="-1"><div class="message-2CShn3 cozyMessage-1DWF9U wrapper-30-Nkg cozy-VmLDNB zalgo-26OfGz" role="article" data-list-item-id="chat-messages___chat-messages-1041534337184710696" tabindex="-1" aria-setsize="-1" aria-roledescription="Message" aria-labelledby="message-username-
```

// further down the hierachy V

```
<div id="message-content-1041534337184710696" class="markup-eYLPri messageContent-2t3eCI">@@@Dahsnxj</div>
```

now I can get the console to show me my search wild card but only that. I cannot get it to spit all the information I need.

code example:

```
element => element.textContent)
      
       if (pumps = (await page.content()).match('@@@')){

        

        for (const pump of pumps){
        let tish = (await page.content('div[class="markup-eYLPri messageContent-2t3eCI"]', element => element.textContent), pump) 
       
        console.log(tish);
        } 
       }
```

the console reads back:

```
li[data-dnd-name="lk-ticket-lk_jinx"]
@@@
li[data-dnd-name="lk-ticket-xlilkamx"]
```

but I need it to write "@@@userNameHere"

as for my ticket in discord reads:

```
    Ticket Tool
BOT
 — 11/13/2022
@=/ Welcome, Please type in your Roblox Username!
TYPE IN YOUR ROBLOX USERNAME NOT YOUR DISPLAY NAME!!!!!

TicketTool.xyz - Ticketing without clutter
=/ — 11/13/2022
please dont delete my ticket or type in here ty
@@@Dahsnxj
```

as you can see the string im trying to get into a var is 'Dahsnxj' and I just cant get it.

any help is appreciated and please excuse my wild var names as I just got frustrated trying to get it to work. ty, also sorry if im not wording my question properly I am more than happy to answer questions.

Comment: This code looks weird. `let pump = ` is ignored and overwritten on the next line. Please share a [mcve]--probably you're selecting the wrong element. Naming-wise `for (const pumps of pump)` is usually `for (const pump of pumps)`. Arrays are plural.

Comment: tysm for your time, your response is helpful already, I do my best to respond with more info so its easier to help, I will edit the original post

Comment: Although I don't think I'm following your code properly or may be even your question. It looks like you are trying to capture the username `@@@Dahsnxj` using the regular expression `'@@@'`. That regex will only match exactly the `@@@` portion of the username and the regex should probably be `'@@@\w+` to include the `'Dahsnxj'` bit too.

Comment: To help debugging, what is the result of `await page.content()`? What is `page`? What are `pumps` and `tish` supposed to be (good naming of variables is a must in programming)?

Comment: @KateLibby I think you should rewrite your question with more details, mainly your code which is cut and difficult to understand. I am agree with phuzi about the misuse of match, you can check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match

Comment: phuzi I seriously love you right now. so the '@@@\w+ is that a typo? cause it wont even run when I try that but yes I can get the @@@ in the console and you did understand my question perfectly! so sorry being cryptic, like I said in the other post I was lost until I read your responses

Comment: heading there now ElJackiste, and thanks again to both of you... sincerely ty.

Comment: To use a backslashes in athe code you will need to escape them, so the regular expression `@@@\w+` will become `@@@\\w+` in your code --> `.match('@@@\\w+')`

Comment: No problem, the key to getting a good answer is asking a good question. You need to pretend (realise) that we have no idea what you are doing and explain the steps you took to attempt to debug your problem and including the relevant code and inputs with the expected and actual outputs. Like most things, the more practice you get the easier it will become.

Comment: OMG!!!! I got it!!!!!!! oh my I really really love you right now! TY so much stranger TY TY TY TY TY!!!!! just that tiny little bit of info did it "in your code --> .match('@@@\\w+')"
Im so fricken happy I broke down in that other question. TY so much stranger I wish I could rank you a million times! You really made my day! 
You are right I thought my question was detailed but maybe my skill isnt good yet I dunno whatever the reason, Im so happy you took the time <3

Comment: sorry for being noob here but how do I credit phuzi and highlight his answer? Wow still flying high from their response lol

Comment: @phuzi Should write an answer here so that you can accept it and credit that answer.

Comment: @Esko I was already on it ;o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I don't think I'm following your code properly or may be even your question. It looks like you are trying to capture the username `@@@Dahsnxj` using the regular expression `@@@`.

That regex will only match exactly the `'@@@'` portion of the username and the regex should probably be `@@@\w+` to include the `'Dahsnxj'` bit too.

So your `.match('@@@')` will become

```
.match('@@@\\w+')
```